# Android equivalent of NSOutlineView

Tags: android, nsoutlineview

I'm looking for something similar to the OS X / iOS  NSOutlineView, basically a class which encapsulates something like a table which is also hierarchical and allows opening and closing of subordinate parts of the outline.  So far I have been unsuccessful in my search, even on developer.android.com, which leads me to believe that maybe Android does not have such a thing.  However, this seems hard to believe, given how ubiquitous outlines and hierarchical structures are.  Am I missing something, or how is something like this generally done on the Android platform?   How would one port code relying on such a construct to Android?

Comment: "a vertically scrolling two-level list"  ... only two levels deep?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Michael have a look on my implementation an android counterpart of the NSOutlineView based on the RecyclerViewAdapter.

https://github.com/willybaer/WDTreeList

Peace up